# Dataset: text and music

Tags: data-request, music

I'm searching for a dataset that contains news and matching music over emotions, topic, etc. Where I find such a dataset?

Comment: Um ... so you're looking for recommended music to play when giving news that there's been a [building collapse](http://www.washingtonpost.com/local/crime/buildings-collapse-on-k-street-in-northwest-washington/2014/05/02/7c839728-d233-11e3-937f-d3026234b51c_story.html) ... but if you run with the lede that a [strip club was affected by the collapse](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/national/dc-strip-club-forced-evacuate-building-collapse-article-1.1777610), do you need different music?  (disclaimer : I used to be an admin & webmaster on Fark.com ~15 years ago)

Comment: I want a dataset that a human read a text such as breaking news, historical data, etc. and select at least one appropriate piece of music for the text. In several papers they create their own dataset through surveys, but I don't find any open data.

Comment: there are some ways to classify music by mood (key, tempo, changes in volume, etc.), but the news is a much stranger thing ... because it's all about how you pitch it.  When I wrote headlines for Fark, I found the most fun it taking mostly mundane stories and writing a pitch for why it should be funny.  Sometimes the humor was just under which category you filed it (eg, 'PSA', as if it were supposed to be informative)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen http://freemusicarchive.org/search/ which has an API (http://freemusicarchive.org/api/docs/) as well as categories like `eerie`, `happy`, and `sad`